# AutoCompleteTextView выдает ошибку "on a null object reference" при любом исходе

Tags: android-fragment, adapter, autocompletetextview

Все перерыл. Даже не знаю в чем проблема. Пробовал не во фрагменте, а просто в чистом проекте. Все равно вылетает эта ошибка. Помогите плиз.

XML код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.gallery.GalleryFragment">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/brandActv"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:dropDownAnchor="@+id/button_change"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/brands"
            android:textColor="#a39d9d" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Далее код:

```
package com.example.bull_application_01.ui.gallery;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.bull_application_01.MainActivity;
import com.example.bull_application_01.R;
import com.example.bull_application_01.databinding.FragmentGalleryBinding;
import com.example.bull_application_01.ui.home.HomeFragment;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    AutoCompleteTextView brandActv;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    TextView testTV;

    final String[] mCats = { "Мурзик", "Рыжик", "Барсик", "Борис",
            "Мурзилка", "Мурка" };


    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;
    private FragmentGalleryBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        galleryViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
        
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, null);
        testTV = root.findViewById(R.id.testedTV);

        brandActv = (AutoCompleteTextView) root.findViewById(R.id.brandActv);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mCats);
        brandActv.setThreshold(1); //will start working from first character
        brandActv.setAdapter(adapter);

        return root;
    }

    //    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается ошибка была в XML коде.
нужно убрать:
android:dropDownAnchor="@+id/button_change"

и все будет работать!